# Finland business visa asks to cancel current Germany WP visa

Tags: visas, germany, business-travel, finland, work-permit

I have a valid German work permit visa for 6 months. However, I have never used that visa as the project for which I had it for got cancelled.
I have applied for a Finland business visa within that duration for another project.
But, the Finland consulate asked to cancel the current German work permit visa before proceeding on the Finland business visa.

Why is it required to cancel my existing work permit visa?

Comment: If that is a a type D long-stay visa, and it is still valid, then what do you need to Finnish visa for? It should already allow you to make short visits to the Schengen area, which includes Finland.

Comment: Yes it is D long-stay visa. But I have never visited to Germany on that visa. Also that is client specific visa I guess, that project got cancelled. Can I still use that visa and travel to Finland?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be no point in issuing a *short-stay* Schengen visa as long as you have a valid national type D visa from Germany, because **the type D visa already allows you to do everything a short-stay visa would allow you to do**, including a short visit to Finland.

The Finnish consulate apparently has rules not to issue visas that would be pointless. (We haven't been able to locate the exact chapter and verse in the Schengen rules that say they *must* refuse such an application, but presumably they at least don't want the PR fallout of taking application fees from travelers who don't need what they'd be paying for). They're helpfully suggesting that they could cancel the German visa if you *really really* want a Finnish one instead -- but you shouldn't *need* one.

The *work permit* part of what you have may be specific to one client, but a long-stay visa is a long-stay visa as far as the Schengen rules are concerned, and those are what Finnish border guards (and border guards elsewhere in the Schengen area) are following.

Comment: That should be right. But If I have Germany D visa, I will have to travel first to Germany and then to Finland right? Further on that, Finland consulate called and told that you have to answer to Germany Immigration officer if you want to travel on D type visa.

Comment: @Vishal: No, there is no such rule on the books. Holders of type D visas can cross into the Schengen area at _any_ external border point. [Article 6, subsection 1(b), second half](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407).